# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService - Issues with importing module that uses Mongoose with a provider

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

since a few hours, I can't resolve the following issue with my NestJS application:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, DentalLabsService, JwtService). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1](https://github.com/PeHo89/brigg-dental) is available in the AuthModule context.

I have an AuthService that uses three Services: DentistsService, DentalLabsService, JwtService. Each of the services is part of a different module. These two Services (DentistsService and DentalLabsService) have again dependencies (MongoDB / Mongoose). A provider constant provides database specifics to the services. The main important structure looks like the following:

**auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(
        private dentistsService: DentistsService,
        private dentalLabsService: DentalLabsService,
        private jwtService: JwtService) {}

    //further code here
}
```

**dentists.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DentistsService {
    constructor(
        @Inject('DENTIST_MODEL')
        private dentistModel: Model<Dentist>,
    ) {}

    //further code here...
}
```

**dentists.providers.ts**

```
export const dentistsProviders = [
    {
        provide: 'DENTIST_MODEL',
        useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model('Dentist', DentistSchema),
        inject: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION'],
    },
];
```

The whole project can be found in my [repository](https://github.com/PeHo89/brigg-dental) on GitHub.

What has to be done (imported and/or exported) in order to make the AuthService aware of the database specifics from the dependent DentistsService and DentalLabService?

I would be very grateful for any help on this issue!

Many thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a minute to find it, but you have a circular dependency between *files*, but not necessarily between the services themselves (due to how you're making use of static methods). If you look at the imports of `auth.service.ts` you are importing `denstists.service.ts` and in `dentists.service.ts` you are importing `auth.service.ts`, thus making a circular dependency, which is also why Nest doesn't give a good error message about what it can't resolve and just has `dependency` instead of `DentistsService`.

Comment: Many many thanks @JayMcDoniel! Resolving the circular dependency fixed the issue! Great!